# How to add objects from website to Local object repository of QTP?

Tags: automation, qtp

When i am trying to add any object from website to local object repository,it is not possible because for each object it is showing same properties.so for descriptive programming it is difficult to mention the property value.

Answer (score 0):

If each object is showing same properties then the either app is not properly recognized by qtp or you have not selected a proper add-in.

For Example, flex applications are not recognized by qtp without customization and qtp will all the objects as MacromediaFlashPlayer object.

Comment: The website which i want to test is having word press as cms and using php language.Please tell me which add-in i need to select in QTP 10.0 trial version ?

Comment: To do automation testing of a website ,which add-in i need to select in QTP 10.0?

Answer (score 0):

Kus, QTP 11 has a feature called **Visual Relation Identifiers**. By the name itself, it helps you identify objects, based on their visual proximity to the other objects in your screen, rather than by their actual properties. This is the remedy for cases when the objects in the AUT are very similar to each other.

This feature is available under the Define New Test Object window.

### Update:

Since you're bound to QTP 10, I suggest using **location** or **ordinal identifiers**. Here, the idea is that even if you have 3 objects that are exactly the same they will at least appear on different locations on the screen and QTP can use that order to identify which object you want to act on. It reads from left to right.

Let's say you have 3 textboxes named "inputField", you can identify them this way:

```
.WebEdit("name:=inputField","location:=0").Set "1stTextBox"
.WebEdit("name:=inputField","location:=1").Set "2ndTextBox"
.WebEdit("name:=inputField","location:=2").Set "3rdTextBox"
```

Read more at this link: [Ordinal Identifiers Demo](http://relevantcodes.com/descriptive-programming-dp-concepts-3-ordinal-identifiers-demo/).

Comment: Thanks Ronixus with QTP 11 its  fine but i want to resolve this issue in QTP 10.0.

Comment: Noted Kus, please see my revised answer.